# Flutter web doesn't show something after upgrade to version 2

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I just upgrade flutter to version 2 and try to run the Web project by typing: `flutter run -d chrome`.
But the result in the browser is a white screen without any error in the console.
My `flutter doctor` result is: [image: flutter doctor commande]
What can I do? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you are upgraded from flutter stable your project may not contain web files, for this you have to run

```
flutter create .
```

in your project root directory to get necessary web related files or any missing files of flutter template.